# nullable double types to excel range in c#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

How to add null-able double types to an excel range in c#

example:
double?[,] to excel.range

or is there any option to add null value in double datatypes?

Comment: Pass a Double or NULL, nullable types are not entertained by excel range.

Answer (score 0):

Nullable types is a feature of the .net framework. Excel doesn't know anything about nullable types and null values.

What value should be displayed in Excel cells in case of null values?